# Is it safe to use Promise.allSettled in this use case?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, ioredis

I am trying to write a script that involves redis operations.

So after every minute, I call the `testFunction` (given below) this function gets all the keys till current minute from a redis sorted set (`test_sorted_set`) (each key in this sorted set represents another sorted set) then I call `processData` and `processSet` in parallel to make code execution faster. However, I am worried this might cause issues as `processSet` deletes some items from the member sorted set while `processData` gets the length of that sorted set.

Is using `promise.allSettled` correct in this scenario or should I instead go for two separate awaits?

```js
const testFunction=async()=>{
  //ts for current minute
  let date = new Date();
  date.setUTCSeconds(0);
  date.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
  const currentTimestamp = date.getTime();

  //gets all keys till current minute (ZRANGE)
  let [keys, rangeError] = await cacheService.getDataInRange(
    'test_sorted_set',
    '-inf',
    currentTimestamp,
    'BYSCORE'
  );
  for (let member of keys) {
    const results = await Promise.allSettled([
      processData(member),
      processSet(member),
    ]);
    let processSetSuccess = true;
    for (let promiseResult of results) {
      const [_, processSetError] = promiseResult['value'];
      if (processSetError) {
        processSetSuccess = false;
        console.log(
          'Something went wrong while processing: ',
          processSetError
        );
      }
    }
    if (processSetSuccess) {
      //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Process Data function:

```js
const processData = async (member) => {
  //get length of member sorted set(zlen)
  const [count, countErr] = await cacheService.getSortedSetLength(member);
  if (countErr) {
    return [null, countErr];
  }

  let key = getKey(member);
  //3 get data from hash for particular key
  let [currentArr, hashError] = await cacheService.getFieldFromHash(
    "test_data",
    key,
  );
  if (hashError) {
    return [null, hashError];
  }
  let hashArray = [];
  currentArr = JSON.parse(currentArr);
  if (currentArr && currentArr.length > 0) {
    //array already present
    hashArray = await getNewArray(currentArr, count, timestamp);
  } else {
    //new entry
    hashArray = await getNewArray([], count, timestamp);
  }

  //4 Add updated array to hash
  const [addSuccess, addErr] = await cacheService.addToHash(
    "test_data",
    key,
    JSON.stringify(hashArray),
  );
  if (addErr) {
    return [null, addErr];
  }
  return [true, null];
};
```

Process set function:

```js
const processSet = async (member) => {
  //Remove all keys with 0 score
  const [removeSuccess, removeErr] = await cacheService.removeByScore(
    member,
    0,
    0,
  );

  let newSortedSetKey = getNextTimestamp(member);

  let newTS = parseInt(newSortedSetKey.split("_")[1]);
  //Store Difference between current and next set in a temporary sorted set
  const [_, diffErr] = await cacheService.storeSortedSetDifference(
    `${newSortedSetKey}_temp`,
    member,
    newSortedSetKey,
  );

  //Combine the temporary set and next set (union)
  const [destCount, unionErr] = await cacheService.unionStore(
    newSortedSetKey,
    newSortedSetKey,
    `${newSortedSetKey}_temp`,
  );

  if (destCount > 0) {
    //push to test_keys
    const [addKeysSuccess, addKeysError] = await cacheService.addToSortedSet(
      "sorted_set_1",
      newTS,
      newSortedSetKey,
    );
  }

  const [delSuccess, delError] = await cacheService.deleteDataStructure(
    `${newSortedSetKey}_temp`,
  );
  return [true, null];
};
```

Redis Service functions:

```
const getSortedSetLength = async (setKey) => {
    const [data, err] = await redisConnection.zcard(setKey);
    if (err) {
      console.log('REDIS ERROR');
      console.log(err);
      captureException(err);
    }
    return [data, err];
  };


  const removeByScore = async (key, minScore, maxScore) => {
    const [data, err] = await redisConnection.zremrangebyscore(key, minScore, maxScore);
    if (err) {
      console.log('REDIS ERROR');
      console.log(err);
      captureException(err);
    }
    return [data, err];
  };
```

Comment: If one relies on the other async operation to be complete, then yes, you should await one then do the other. If one does not rely on the other, then you can run them both at the same time?

Comment: Can you provide the code for the functions `processData` and `processSet`? Chances are that there is some misunderstanding of what runs "in parallel" and what not... For instance, if these functions don't use `await`, all their code just executes synchronously, and `processSet` will only run when `processData` has completed.

Comment: @trincot I have added the code for functions. Both of them have async operations (redis operations)

Comment: *"processSet deletes some items from the member sorted set"*: where exactly does this happen?

Comment: @trincot

`cacheService.removeByScore`

Comment: To answer this question we need to see the code for `getSortedSetLength` and `removeByScore`.

Comment: @trincot I have added the code for them as well!

Comment: OK, this gets tedious, because now it depends on the implementation of these `redisConnection` functions. It really is necessary to drill down to the code where the length is retrieved **synchronously** and where the removal is actually **performed**. With the given info it is still not clear what will happen first, so if you want to play it safe, then yes, you should not call both functions like that. I am going to abandon this question, sorry.